# Generate synthetic trajectory dataset that has global coverage

Tags: large-datasets, trajectory, global

I want to generate a spatial trajectory dataset which basically contains tuples - (lat,lon,time), grouped together by an identifier so they form trajectories. In addition, I want this dataset to have global coverage.

I would prefer to use [AIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) or [ADS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_dependent_surveillance_%E2%80%93_broadcast), however, these datasets are not free and the ones that are free have only regional coverage. So, for my study purpose I want to create a synthetic dataset that resembles these datasets.

My purpose is to try different tools (python lib or Postgres extensions) to manage and visualize large trajectory data. How can I generate large trajectory data?

Comment: Have you considered adapting an emulator so that it generates files?  https://github.com/scadaperspective/Simulator_pi

Comment: If you have tried it, it will be helpful if you can provide more information on how to implement it. Github page does not have instructions.

Comment: What is a trajectory to you? Are straight lines between random coordinates enough? Are geodesics?

Comment: Trajectory  could be like  a GPS track with set of points (lat, long, timestamp) between origin and destination. Origin and destination can be random coordinates on the globe.